# I can't convert from HFS+ to APFS an external SSD volume I created for testing

Tags: apfs

I created an external volume with macOS High Sierra.  When I try to convert it to APFS with Disk Utility, the "convert to APFS" is greyed out.  I tried unmounting the volume first, then it's not greyed out, but when I try to convert, I get this error: *The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.DiskManagement error -69546.)*.

I heard that having "cloned" a volume may prevent it from being converted to APFS.  I don't remember if I cloned it or not.  I created it with El Capitan, then upgraded it to High Sierra.  Now it won't convert to APFS.

Any way to do the conversion? such as terminal command or something?

Comment: How much space is free on your external HFS+ volume?

Comment: Is it GUID or MBR?

Comment: An attempted Terminal conversion at least explains the error: "Error: -69546: Conversion to APFS of a macOS system volume is only allowed in the OS Installer Environment".

Comment: You are trying to convert a HS boot volume (booted to another HS volume). Boot to the external volume and re-try on the command line (`diskutil ap convert...` - check the man page of diskutil)!

Comment: @klanomath: You'll get the same error, i.e. "conversion is only allowed in the OS Installer Environment" (see my comment above).<br>

Comment: @Redarm According to this [article](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/upgrade-mac-apfs-after-high-sierra/) (and some more) it should work at least in *some* Recovery Mode.

Comment: @klanomath I just checked through the external USB disk's Recovery partition unsuccessfully.  The only way I can see is to format the volume to APFS first (or somehow mimic the installer environment, if that's possible at all).

Comment: Carrying on through the comments, unmounting the volume in Recovery then does then enable the "Convert to APFS" menu in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/upgrade-mac-apfs-after-high-sierra/) and [this](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/convert-macos-volume-apfs-high-sierra/) article the post-install conversion to APFS should work in Recovery Mode:

> 1. Boot the Mac into Recovery Mode by holding down the Command and R keys until you see the macOS Utilities screen.
> 2. Open Disk utility.
> 3. Choose your boot volume [the external boot drive].<sup>1</sup>
> 4. Click on the Edit menu
> 5. Click on Convert to APFS
> 6. When prompted with “Would you like to convert  to APFS?”
> 7. click on the Convert button.
>      When the process is finished, click on the Done button.

<sup>1</sup>: According to Redarm's comment you have to unmount the volume additionally!

---

I can't test this myself - your mileage may vary.

Comment: If you add "unmount the volume" after step 3, I can upvote your answer.

Comment: @Redarm Did you test this?

Comment: I spoke too soon: while unmounting the volume in Recovery does let me convert it to APFS, it then does not boot: "Running bless to place boot files failed."  Option booting also does not list the volume.  The container seems malformed with no Preboot, VM, or Recovery volumes included.  Maybe if I run the install assistant over it?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it and am in the process of running the install assistant (aka full installer) over the installation, to hopefully create the Preboot, Recovery and VM volumes within the container, as they are missing.  That will hopefully leave me with a bootable volume and an additional "Recovery" from the old HFS+ volume.

Comment: Just to add: that the install assistant did create the missing volumes within the container and even cleaned up the Recovery HD from the old installation onto the HFS+ formatted volume.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, here's a summary of what I did:
- Boot to recovery partition (Start and hold Command + R)

- From Disk Utility, unmount the volume you want to convert to APFS 

- Convert to APFS (Edit > convert to APFS) (this renders the volume unbootable)…to make it bootable again:

- Install High Sierra on it, it won’t delete anything (I did so by using the 10.13 installer volume I had in the same SSD)

- It worked!

Answer (score 3):

To add to klanomath's answer, which does convert the system volume to APFS, but leaves it in an un-bootable state: 
download the High Sierra install assistant (aka full installer) and either [create a bootable installation volume](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372), or use it from a different High Sierra volume, if available.

Then run the installer over the newly converted APFS volume.

This is non-destructive and will leave all user files in place, but it will create the missing "Preboot", "Recovery" and "VM" volumes within the APFS container, which makes the volume bootable and cleans up any left-over Recovery HD from the previous (HFS+ formatted) installation.